# Missing scrollbar when opening another page from a bootstrap popup modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, single-page-application

I am using bootsrap-3 and angular to build SPA. I have many modal popups and those popup has links which lead to other pages and those pages need scrolling (length in nature). But when I open any of those page from a modal popup (bootstap modal) the scroll bar is not visible, I need a refresh to see the scroll bar.

If anyone have gone through such issue and got a solution, please suggest how can I fix this.

Comment: look at class added to body tag, and css associated, when modal is initialized. The body overflow is set to hidden

Comment: Are you using Angular UI Bootstrap, or...?

Comment: Thanks @charlie 'modal-open' class and some style are left behind to the body tag.  Now I can figure out a work around.

Comment: Can you tell me how you fixed this..

Comment: @JavascriptCoder In my earlier comment I point out that 'model-open' class does not removed when popup is closed. So you try to remove the class when popup is closed or simply change the css to `.modal-open {   overflow: auto;}`